# cannot override with a stored property shouldRemovePresentersView()

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

I'm trying to provide my own version that overrides some of this behavior, in particular telling UIKit to leave the MyController visible.

```
import UIKit

class DimmingPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

    override var shouldRemovePresentersView: Bool

}
```

but I receive several errors, such as:

```
Cannot override with a stored property 'shouldRemovePresentersView'
Getter for 'shouldRemovePresentersView' with Objective-C selector 'shouldRemovePresentersView' conflicts with getter for 'shouldRemovePresentersView' from superclass 'UIPresentationController' with the same Objective-C selector
```

Actually, I was rewriting working on Swift 2 method, which is not convenient to swift 3 any more:

```
override func shouldRemovePresentersView() -> Bool {
return false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the parentheses, replace `func` with `var` and exchange the *arrow* with a colon, the method has been turned into a property:

```
override var shouldRemovePresentersView : Bool {
    return false
}
```